# Flutter web + go_router, when direct visit to: /page, how to go back to / (root)

Tags: flutter, flutter-navigation, flutter-go-router

I am using `go_router` and got such config:

```dart
final router = GoRouter(
  initialLocation: '/',
  routes: [
    GoRoute(path: '/', pageBuilder: (context, state) => const MaterialPage(child: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page')),),
    GoRoute(path: '/second', pageBuilder: (context, state) => const MaterialPage(child: MyHomePage(title: 'Second !')),),
  ],
);
```

When I visit web directly using: `/second` page opens correctly, but there is no way to go back to: `/` (no back arrow in the App bar).

If I go to `/` and then open `/second` page via: `context.push("/second");` then naturally back arrow is present.

When I type URI directly in the browser, how can I make sure that App bar back arrow allows me to go to the initial page?

Full example:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:go_router/go_router.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

final router = GoRouter(
  initialLocation: '/',
  routes: [
    GoRoute(path: '/', pageBuilder: (context, state) => const MaterialPage(child: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page')),),
    GoRoute(path: '/second', pageBuilder: (context, state) => const MaterialPage(child: MyHomePage(title: 'Second !')),),
  ],
);

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp.router(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      routerConfig: router,
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key, required this.title});

  final String title;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            const Text(
              '',
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {
          context.push("/second");
        },
        tooltip: 'Navigate',
        child: const Icon(Icons.navigate_next),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For back to root from app bar any where use this:

```
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            const Text(
              '',
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {
          Navigator.of(context, rootNavigator: true).pushAndRemoveUntil(
            MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (context) => const  MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page')),
            (route) => true);
        },
        tooltip: 'Navigate',
        child: const Icon(Icons.navigate_next),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

You can use this code to back root:

```
  Navigator.of(context, rootNavigator: true).pushAndRemoveUntil(
            MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (context) => const  MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page')),
            (route) => true);
```

Comment: Well, in my case I can use: `context.go("/");`, but that's not the point. The point is to have the back arrow present in the App bar, as if the root was there. You answer disregards fact that I am using router.

Comment: What exactly do you mean?
Do you want to return to the root or return to the previous page?

Comment: Ideally I would like to return to the root via `AppBar` as if it was the previous page.

Comment: I have updated the answer, the only way to return to the root from any page is this. Good luck

Comment: Thanks for your effort, but your answer doesn't really answer my question, it also uses Navigator approach which isn't remotely close to the router approach and your comment disregards the solution that I've added earlier on.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to nest routes e.g. like this:

```dart
routes: [
    GoRoute(path: '/', pageBuilder: (context, state) => const MaterialPage(child: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page')), routes: [
      GoRoute(path: 'second', pageBuilder: (context, state) => const MaterialPage(child: MyHomePage(title: 'Second !'))), 
    ]),
  ],
```

In which case when you visit: `/second` directly, the `/` page will be on the stack.

It is possible to test the "back arrow" behavior without web browser, by going to `/second` directly without pushing page on stack: `context.go("/second");`